# Python autocomplete not working in python2.7 but works in python3

Tags: bash, python-2.7, autocomplete

I have this in my ~/.pythonrc file:

```
# ~/.pythonrc
# enable syntax completion
try:
    import readline
except ImportError:
    print("Module readline not available.")
else:
    import rlcompleter
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
```

This works on a remote server but not on my MacBookPro. Any ideas why?

Note: This works on my Mac when I use python3, but not python (version 2.7)

Comment: https://nicolas.perriault.net/code/2010/python-tab-completion/

Comment: I guess you need to source the file

Comment: @MrE - I just realized this works on my Mac when I use `python3`, but not `python` (version 2.7)